# NameError: name 'my_agg' is not defined error when using staticmethod in python

Tags: python, pandas

I get the following error when executing the **process_df()** function:

**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "", line 23, in process_df
NameError: name 'my_agg' is not defined**

I'm not quite sure why I thought with self.my_agg this should work

```
class DataPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.combined_df = None
        self.df_overall = None 

    def run_script(self):
        self.run_query()  # return new_df in memory
        self.process_df()
  
    def run_query(self):
        """ Run query  """
        query = pd.read_csv('')
        combined_df = query.fillna('NaN')
        self.combined_df = combined_df 
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def my_agg(x):
        names = {'Customers': x['customer_id'].nunique(),'Purchases':  x['total_purchases'].sum()}
        return pd.Series(names, index=['Customers', 'Purchases'])

    def process_df(self):
        combined_df = self.combined_df
        df_overall = combined_df.groupby(['date', 'store']).apply(self.my_agg())
        # Flatten the pivot table to get a datafrmae
        df_overall = pd.DataFrame(df_overall.to_records())
        self.df_overall = df_overall
        return self 


report = DataPipeline()
report.run_script()
print(report.df_overall)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a method, you should call it with parentheses, i.e., "self.my_agg()", not "self.my_agg".

Comment: I did but I'm keep getting the same error